Get width of a composable without rendering it
I want a Text composable that displays day-of-week i.e. - monday, tuesday, wednesday etc.... with the width fixed to the width of same composable for the longest day-of-week.
In english it would be "Wednesday", so all composables should be having the same width as  the composable of "wednesday". But my app supports localisation, so i cant just hardcode the width to wednesday.
My code so far:
@Composable
fun DayOfWeekText(date: LocalDate) {
    val longestDayOfWeek =
        DayOfWeek.entries.toTypedArray()
            .map { it.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()) }
            .maxBy { it.length }
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var width by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    Text(// I dont want this to be rendered
        modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { width = with(density) { it.size.width.toDp() } },
        text = longestDayOfWeek,
    )
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.width(width),
        text = date.dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()),
    )
}

The above solution works except for it rendering the text which i need to measure

I think what you're looking for is already available in compose. See TextMeasurer https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextMeasurer

As suggested by @onur-d we can use TextMeasurer() to measure the longest day-of-week text without rendering, and then use its width as the Text composable.
val DayOfWeek.text
    get() = getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault())


@Composable
private fun DayOfWeekText(date: LocalDate) {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall.copy(
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
    val longestDayOfWeekText = remember(textMeasurer, textStyle) {
        DayOfWeek.entries.toTypedArray().maxOf { textMeasurer.measure(it.text).size.width }
    }
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.width(with(density) { longestDayOfWeekText.toDp() }),
        text = date.dayOfWeek.text,
        style = textStyle
    )
}


